# Can't run Xcode simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I am running Xcode 9.1 and recently rebooted my computer. Prior to rebooting I could run the simulator with no problems. After rebooting I get this message.

"Enter the name and password of a user in the developer tools group"

[image]

I am running this on my own personal machine (provided by my school) and should have administrator access with my login.

I have looked at other posts relating to this message and attempted the following solutions to no avail.

When I run "*DevToolsSecurity ~enable"* it tells me that developer mode is already enabled.

When I run "*sudo dscl . append /Groups/_developer GroupMembership myUserName"*

I got a message saying my user name was not in the subdoers file.

I am at a total loss on how to resolve this problem and admit that I am not a professional programmer.  I am just a guy who is trying to figure out how to write some basic apps using Xcode.  Any help would be GREATLY APPRECIATED!

Answer (score 1):

Everything about what you’ve written indicates that you do not have administrative access to your machine.  You can confirm this from System Preferences -> Users & Groups or checking the output of running ‘id’ from Terminal (you’ll probably not see the admin group listed).